# SQL selecting rows by most recent date with one unique column (selecting 3+ columns)

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

In my postgres db I have a table `my_table` with columns `ean`, `price`, `dtmod`

| ean | price | dtmod |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 155105 | 2.19 | 2022-06-22 03:03:25.43045+02 |
| 155105 | -0.01 | 2022-06-28 02:27:15.478475+02 |
| 155105 | 1.45 | 2022-06-28 15:11:35.558692+02 |
| 114695 | -0.01 | 2022-06-28 02:27:15.448782+02 |
| 114695 | 5.99 | 2022-06-28 15:11:27.689637+02 |
| 213786 | -0.01 | 2022-06-28 02:27:15.468477+02 |
| 213786 | 2.39 | 2022-06-28 15:11:32.284314+02 |

How can I filter data in this table in order to get the latest `dtmod` for each unique `ean` (and also showing the `price`), ordered by `ean`?

Expected Output:

| ean | price | dtmod |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 114695 | 5.99 | 2022-06-28 15:11:27.689637+02 |
| 155105 | 1.45 | 2022-06-28 15:11:35.558692+02 |
| 213786 | 2.39 | 2022-06-28 15:11:32.284314+02 |

I have found a possible solution, but I think it is not the most concise and efficient one.

step 1:
extract the latest date for all the ean

```
select ean, max(dtmod) 
from my_table 
group by ean;
```

> ```
>   ean   |              max              
> --------+-------------------------------
>  155105 | 2022-06-28 15:11:35.558692+02
>  114695 | 2022-06-28 15:11:27.689637+02
>  213786 | 2022-06-28 15:11:32.284314+02
> ```

step 2:
extract ean, price and dtmod from my_table where ean and price match the results from the previous query

```
select ean, price, dtmod 
from my_table 
where (ean, dtmod) in 
     (
     select ean, max(dtmod) 
     from my_table 
     group by ean
     ) 
order by ean;
```

> ```
>    ean  | price  |            dtmod       
> --------+--------+------------------------------
>  114695 |   5.99 | 2022-06-28 15:11:27.689637+02
>  155105 |   1.45 | 2022-06-28 15:11:35.558692+02
>  213786 |   2.39 | 2022-06-28 15:11:32.284314+02
> ```

Any suggestions on how to improve the query?

Comment: can you share your dbms?

Comment: @lemon. It's postgres, question updated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postgresql+greatest-n-per-group

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The classic way to do this and still very useful in this case:

```
select 
  ean, 
  price,
  dtmod
from my_table t0
where
  t0.dtmod = (
    select max(dtmod) 
    from my_table t1 
    where t1.ean = t0.ean
  )
order by ean
;
```

Also, super helpful for everyone is to know how to use the window functions, any SQL programmer should spend some time to understand all of the window functions.

```
with
w_o as (
  select
  ean,
  price,
  dtmod,
  row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY ean ORDER BY dtmod DESC) rn
  from my_table
)
select
  ean,
  price,
  dtmod
from w_o
where rn = 1
order by ean
;
```

Note:

For testing, I added a duplicate record with same EAN, and same timestamp to the test data. The first query gives both the second gives only one. You can determine which one it returns by tuning the ordering.

Edit 1.
I forgot the order by. :)

Edit 2.
Added window function information.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/8278a/1/1

Answer (score 2):

You can use the handy `FETCH FIRST <n> ROWS WITH TIES` clause, combined with a ranking, given by the biggest dtmod for each "*ean*".

```
SELECT * 
FROM tab
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ean ORDER BY dtmod DESC)
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS WITH TIES
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2P3kntc1FXKPSrXRZvYHHE/1).

Answer (score 1):

Your query would be like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (ean)
    ean, 
    LAST_VALUE(price) OVER (PARTITION BY ean ORDER BY dtmod DESC) AS price, 
    MAX(dtmod) OVER (PARTITION BY ean) AS dtmod
FROM my_table
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=74b1e7bf07b60ec9dba0458bcf5785bc)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple `distinct on` without window functions. (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=4b174cbc8934640970e851d57c177506) )

```
select distinct on (ean) 
       ean
     , price
     , dtmod 
  from my_table
 order by ean, dtmod desc;
```